# Simple algorithm for computing an orderable value from a string

Tags: sorting, strings, es6

I would like to compute a numeric value for strings containing only `/[a-z0-9]/i` (ignore case). Later, I want to use this value for sorting rows. For this post, I am ignoring number also.

My thinking was, that I can define an alphabet like `0123456789a...z` and compute a sortable value by summing up the indexes of each character found, like this (pseudo code but should work in ES6):

```
const alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxzy'.split('');

function easySort(myString) {
  myString = myString.toLowerCase();
  let sortableValue = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
    sortableValue += alpha.indexOf(myString.charAt(i)) + 1; // to avoid 0
  }
  return sortableValue;
};
```

Simple example (assuming indexes a=1, b=2, ..):

```
let arr = ['abc', 'ab', 'abd', 'aba'];
let ordered = arr.sort((a, b) => easySort(a) - easySort(b));
// ordered now is ['ab', 'aba', 'abc', 'abd']
```

The question is, is this a good approach for strings from that alphabet? Are there cases when this would not work the intended way?

I am not asking for improvements of the code but rather the algorithm and whether it may behave unexpected for certain values (by that I do not mean illegal values).

Comment: Strings are already their own numeric, sortable value.  Is it your intention to create a sortable value that takes up less memory?

Comment: Yes it is, instead of the string I do intend to store the numeric value later only.

Comment: Characters of a string are just representations of byte values from an encoding.  Look at the ASCII table, you will see that each character corresponds with a single number that is orderable.  If you are looking to speed up searches, then I advise reading up on various sorting algorithms and find one that is most applicable for your use case and input data.

Comment: Were you referring to hashing. Murmurhash3 is pretty unique. There is also the matter of the hashing trick which uses this and secondary hashing to compute a numeric value with limited collisions. Are you trying to sort an extremely massive set of strings or something that would be better in Spark?

Answer (score 5):

It's a bad approach because it doesn't work. This is basically a question of domain sizes.

Even with only 36 possible characters, there are **vastly** more possible strings than probably fit into the integer type of your choice. That means that pre-computing a sort index doesn't work; you can always get collisions between strings that should be sorted differently but that your index claims to be equal.

Therefore, strings, even from a restricted character set, are their own sorting index, and no smaller sorting index can be correct. If you don't care about exact sorting, just use a fixed-size prefix of each string instead of a complicated transformation.

Comment: While reading your answer I realized that one problem is ambiguity. That's the sort of problems I already suspected (and asked for) but couldn't quite put my finger on it ;)

Comment: The problem is not so much ambiguity. That is a *consequence* of the problem. The problem is, as Kilian wrote, the size of the two domains. If you are talking about *mathematical* integers, then there are *exactly* as many integers as there are strings (both are countably infinite), so your scheme doesn't buy you anything. If we are talking about ECMAScript `Number`s, then there are only finitely many of them, but infinitely many `String`s, which means that you run into the *Pigeonhole Principle*, and there will be at least two strings which have the same number.